# How can I count the number of matching zero elements between two numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two `numpy` arrays of equal size.  They contain the values `1`, `0`, and `-1`.  I can count the number of matching ones and negative ones, but I'm not sure how to count the matching elements that have the same index and value of zero.

I'm a little confused on how to proceed here.

Here is some code:

```
print(actual_direction.shape)
print(predicted_direction.shape)
act = actual_direction
pre = predicted_direction
part1 = act[pre == 1]
part2 = part1[part1 == 1]
result1 = part2.sum()
part3 = act[pre == -1]
part4 = part3[part3 == -1]
result2 = part4.sum() * -1
non_zeros = result1 + result2
zeros = len(act) - non_zeros
print(f'zeros : {zeros}\n')
print(f'non_zeros : {non_zeros}\n')
final_result = non_zeros + zeros
print(f'result1 : {result1}\n')
print(f'result2 : {result2}\n')
print(f'final_result : {final_result}\n')
```

Here is the printout:

```
(11279,)
(11279,)
zeros : 5745.0
non_zeros : 5534.0
result1 : 2217.0
result2 : 3317.0
final_result : 11279.0
```

So what I've done here is simply subtract the summation of the ones and negative ones from the total length of the array.  I can't assume that the difference (zeros: 5745) contains ALL matching elements that contain zeros can I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
import numpy as np

a=np.array([1,0,0,1,-1,-1,0,0])
b=np.array([1,0,0,1,-1,-1,0,1])
summ = np.sum((a==0) & (b==0))
print(summ)
```

Output:

```
3
```

Comment: This solution gives me an array, not a count.

Comment: you put `(predicted_direction==0) & (actual_direction==0)`  inside `np.sum()` yes? I mean, `np.sum((predicted_direction==0) & (actual_direction==0))`... What output you get with `print((predicted_direction==0) & (actual_direction==0))`?

Comment: Hey @brohjoe i'm not sure why are you getting an array... could you comment the output of `print((predicted_direction==0) & (actual_direction==0))`?

Comment: zeros = np.sum((act == 0) & (pre == 0)) prints as '0'.   
zeros = np.sum([act == 0]) & ([pre == 0]) prints as [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]  
zeros = np.sum((act == 0)) & ((pre == 0)) prints as  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]

Comment: Don´t print the sum, just print the list, I mean `print((predicted_direction==0) & (actual_direction==0))`  to see what is the output...

Comment: print((act == 0) & (pre == 0)) yields [False False False ... False False False], not a count. It's the same result that swier gave.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217282/discussion-between-mrnobody33-and-brohjoe).

Comment: It turns out that there are no matching zeros after exporting the data and comparing.  Sorry for the misunderstanding.  The problem was my data.  I gave you points. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. And yeah, I wrote that possibiliy in the chat, I guessed maybe that was happening. I'll appreciate if you accept the answer too. :)

Comment: Looks like you got about 7 points out of me.  :-)  Thanks a lot!   ヘ( ^o^)ノ＼(^_^ )

Comment: You're welcome :). Please remember [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

**You can use [`numpy.ravel()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) to flatten out the array, then use `zip()` to compare each element side by side:**

```
import numpy as np

ar1 = np.array([[1, 0, 0],
                [0, 1, 1],
                [0, 1, 0]])

ar2 = np.array([[0, 0, 0],
                [1, 0, 1],
                [0, 1, 0]])

count = 0
for e1, e2 in zip(ar1.ravel(), ar2.ravel()):
    if e1 == e2:
        count += 1

print(count)
```

**Output:**

```
6
```

---

**You can also do this to list all the matches found, as well as print out the amount:**

```
dup = [e1 for e1, e2 in zip(ar1.ravel(), ar2.ravel()) if e1 == e2]
print(dup)
print(len(dup))
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
6
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two arrays and want to count the positions where both of these are 0, right?

You can check where the array meets your required condition `(a == 0)`, and then use the 'and' operator `&` to check where both arrays meet your requirement:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
b = np.array([1, 0, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 1])

both_zero = (a == 0) & (b == 0)  # [False,  True, False, False, False, False]

both_zero.sum()  # 1
```

---

In your updated question you appear to be interested in the similarities and differences between actual values and predictions. For this, a [confusion matrix](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html) is ideally suited.

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
confusion_matrix(a, b, labels=[-1, 0, 1])
```

will give you a confusion matrix as output telling you how many -1s were predicted as -1, 0 and 1, and the same for 0 and +1:

```
[[1 1 0]   # -1s predicted as -1, 0 and 1
 [0 1 1]   # 0s predicted as -1, 0 and 1
 [1 1 3]]  # 1s predicted as -1, 0 and 1
```

Comment: Hey, could you explain how is this different to [https://stackoverflow.com/a/62745467/13676202](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62745467/13676202)?

Comment: @MrNobody33 It's not, looks like you were faster, have my upvote!

Comment: @brohjoe I assume your arrays are predicted_direction and  predicted_direction, yes?Did you try with `np.sum((predicted_direction==0) & (actual_direction==0))`?

Comment: Let me try that

Comment: @brohjoe yes it's possible, in the code snipped you commented you forgot a pair of brackets.

Comment: @Swier : turns out my data had no matching zeros.  Sorry for the misunderstanding.  I gave you points.